# how to store drawing rectangle coordinates in percentage in Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In my project I am working on dynamically zone creation and deletion on floor of particular building. To do that would using Raphealjs, using rapheal I am able to create zone on floor. I am storing height, width, startx and stary to database.

But the problem is, it is stores th coordinates in pixels. When I make my screen smaller, the zone going out of my floor. Solution for this I need to store the coordinates in percentage.

Is there any way to do it, Please help me to come out.

Below are my images it is showing clear picture.

When Small screen:

Please give me solution, Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please anybody give solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to scale down/up your fabric objects whenever you are making your screen smaller? My recommendation would be to store a logical points. For example, your canvas size is 500x600 px, and you have rectangle at position x=100, y=100, width=50, and height=50. Logical coordinate will be your actual coordinate in pixels divided by dimension of the canvas. In other words, your

```
logicalX = x/canvas.width (100/500=0.2)
logicalY = y/canvas.height (100/600=0.16666666666666)
width = width/canvas.width (50/500=0.1)
height = height/canvas.height (50/600=0.833333)
```

I this case you will have dynamic coordinates, even if you will load your app with different canvas size from previous session. All the time, whenever you resize your canvas you should recalculate your physical points and render all canvas again. You can assign logical coordinates object to your fabricjs object:

```
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'green',
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  id : someid,
  logicalCoords: {x: 0.2,
                  y: 0.16666666666666,
                  width: 0.1,
                  height: 0.833333}
  });
```

Recalculating physical points will be easy, you should loop through all fabricjs objects and multiply your canvas dimension by logical points:

```
canvas.forEachObject(function(o){ 
   o.x = logicalCoords.x * canvas.width;
   o.x = logicalCoords.y * canvas.height;
   o.x = logicalCoords.width * canvas.width;
   o.x = logicalCoords.height * canvas.height;
});
canvas.renderAll();
```

WARNING: it is not working code, it just an idea how to fix your problem.

**UPDATE 1:**
Fabricjs requires pixel data for drawing shapes. You can do something like this:

```
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
      left: toPixels(percentValueLeftFromDB),
      top: toPixels(percentValueTopFromDB),
      fill: 'green',
      width: toPixels(percentValueWidthFromDB),
      height: toPixels(percentValueHeightFromDB),
      });
function toPixels(value){
//do conversion here..
//you should take care of left and top coordinates
pixelValue = canvas.width * value / 100; //calculates only width and top 
return pixelValue;
```

There is no automation like percentage. You have to do your conversion by yourself. I showed you 2 variations Logical Points to Physical Points, or Percentage points to Physical Points. All the time you need to path Physical points to the Fabricjs. In my opinion, Logical points is more accurate then percentage.

**UPDATE 2:**

Why logical points will be responsive, because it will need all the time viewer size. For example, as you mentioned in comment for different physical screen sizes (in inch), you will have different screen resolutions. Ideally, you will have dynamic canvas size for each resolution, which can be calculated on a fly or set as percentage in CSS. Let's assume you set width = 75% and height = 60% for canvas. If you will open this canvas on different screens or devices your physical width and height of the canvas in pixels will be different. In this case logicalPoint will be on the same spot on each device, because you will need to use canvas dimensions to convert them into physicalPoint.
Let's say your canvas has dimensions 1000x500 px, your rectangle has logical (top,left) coordinate (0.5,0.5), and width = 0.5, and height = 0.5. Physical result will be rectangle at position (500,250) with width = 500 and height = 250. If you will take the same logical coordinates by tries to show them on smaller canvas it will be the same position of the rectangle.

Please, check this simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n27ap6ou/) which shows logical coordinated for 2 canvases.

***ATTENTION:*** This logic will work only if you will keep you canvas size with the same aspect ratio. If you will resize canvas width by 50%, you must resize your height by 50% as well.

Also, fiddle code is here:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="150"  style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="400" height="350"  style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var canvas1 = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');
    var canvas2 = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas2');

    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
       left: logicalToPhysical(0.5, canvas1.width),
       top: logicalToPhysical(0.5, canvas1.height),
       width: logicalToPhysical(0.5, canvas1.width),
       height: logicalToPhysical(0.5, canvas1.height),
       fill: 'rgba(255,127,39,1)'
    });
    canvas1.add(rect);
    canvas1.renderAll();

    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
       left: logicalToPhysical(0.5, canvas2.width),
       top: logicalToPhysical(0.5, canvas2.height),
       width: logicalToPhysical(0.5, canvas2.width),
       height: logicalToPhysical(0.5, canvas2.height),
       fill: 'rgba(255,127,39,1)'
    });
    canvas2.add(rect);
    canvas2.renderAll();
})();

function logicalToPhysical(value, dimension){
    return value * dimension;
}
```

Comment: Sir  have seen any working example which store the coordinates in percentile(I mean responsive)?

Comment: Yes sir, as u said logical points are more accurate but its not responsive right, If I created zone in 15 inch screen system, then i run on 14 inch screen system it may vary right.

Comment: Please look at UPDATE 2